# Access contract's runtime code from one of its functions

Tags: evm, assembly, yul

Is there anyway to access the runtime code of a function from its contract? Using assembly may be?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details - are you trying to access the bytecode onchain or to decompile/debug a contract?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with assembly using the `codecopy` built-in function or `extcodecopy` (see [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/yul.html#evm-dialect)).

Here is an example of a function returning the required portion of the current contract's byte code : `_length` bytes starting from `_pc`, with proper memory management :

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.14;

contract Example {

    function aFunction(uint256 _length, uint256 _pc) public view returns (bytes memory code) {
        assembly {
            // Allocate memory for the byte array
            code := mload(0x40)
            mstore(0x40, add(code, add(0x40, mul(0x20, div(_length, 0x20)))))

            // Set the length of the byte array
            mstore(code, _length)

            // Copy contract's code to the byte array data
            codecopy(add(code, 0x20), _pc, _length)
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this contract with solidity 0.8.14 on default settings, this function's bytecode is :

`0x5b60606040519050602083046020026040018101604052828152828260208301399291505056`

Which is 0x26 (38) bytes long and starts at position 0x60 (96) in the contract's code, you can check it with [this tool](https://ethervm.io/decompile) if you are interested. Calling `aFunction(0x26, 0x60)` makes it return its own bytecode : `0x5b60606040519050602083046020026040018101604052828152828260208301399291505056`

Keep in mind that a contract's code is **read only**. Any modification must be done in memory, this is what deployement bytecodes do to setup `immutable` variables for example.

I hope that answers your question.